# Implementing post / pre increment / decrement when translating to Lua

Tags: lua, pass-by-reference, lua-scripting-library

I'm writing a LSL to Lua translator, and I'm having all sorts of trouble implementing incrementing and decrementing operators.  LSL has such things using the usual C like syntax (x++, x--, ++x, --x), but Lua does not.  Just to avoid massive amounts of typing, I refer to these sorts of operators as "crements".  In the below code, I'll use "..." to represent other parts of the expression.

```
... x += 1 ...
```

Wont work, coz Lua only has simple assignment.

```
... x = x + 1 ...
```

Wont work coz that's a statement, and Lua can't use statements in expressions.  LSL can use crements in expressions.

```
function preIncrement(x)  x = x + 1;  return x;  end
... preIncrement(x) ...
```

While it does provide the correct value in the expression, Lua is pass by value for numbers, so the original variable is not changed.  If I could get this to actually change the variable, then all is good.  Messing with the environment might not be such a good idea, dunno what scope x is.  I think I'll investigate that next.  The translator could output scope details.

Assuming the above function exists -

```
... x = preIncrement(x) ...
```

Wont work for the "it's a statement" reason.

Other solutions start to get really messy.

```
x = preIncrement(x)
... x ...
```

Works fine, except when the original LSL code is something like this -

```
while (doOneThing(x++))
{
  doOtherThing(x);
}
```

Which becomes a whole can of worms.  Using tables in the function -

```
function preIncrement(x)  x[1] = x[1] + 1;  return x[1];  end
temp = {x}
... preincrement(temp) ...
x = temp[1]
```

Is even messier, and has the same problems.

Starting to look like I might have to actually analyse the surrounding code instead of just doing simple translations to sort out what the correct way to implement any given crement will be.  Anybody got any simple ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and thinking I've come up with an idea that might work.

For globals -

```
function preIncrement(x)
  _G[x] = _G[x] + 1
  return _G[x]
end
... preIncrement("x") ...
```

For locals and function parameters (which are locals to) I know at the time I'm parsing the crement that it is local, I can store four flags to tell me which of the four crements is being used in the variables AST structure.  Then when it comes time to output the variables definition, I can output something like this -

```
local x;
function preIncrement_x() x = x + 1;  return x;  end
function postDecrement_x() local y = x;  x = x - 1;  return y;  end
... preIncrement_x() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to really do this properly you're going to have to do some more detailed analysis, and splitting of some expressions into multiple statements, although many can probably be translated pretty straight-forwardly.

Note that at least in C, you can delay post-increments/decrements to the next "sequence point", and put pre-increments/decrements *before* the previous sequence point; sequence points are only located in a few places: between statements, at "short-circuit operators" (`&&` and `||`), etc. [(more info here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

So it's fine to replace `x = *y++ + z * f ();` with `{ x = *y + z * f(); y = y + 1; }`—the user isn't allowed to assume that `y` will be incremented before anything else in the statement, only that the value used in `*y` will be `y` before it's incremented.  Similarly, `x = *--y + z * f();` can be replaced with `{ y = y - 1; x = *y + z * f (); }`

Answer (score 0):

Lua is designed to be pretty much impervious to implementations of this sort of thing. It may be done as kind of a compiler/interpreter issue, since the interpreter can know that variables only change when a statement is executed.

There's no way to implement this kind of thing in Lua. Not in the general case. You could do it for global variables by passing a string to the increment function. But obviously it wouldn't work for locals, or for variables that are in a table that is itself global.

Lua doesn't want you to do it; it's best to find a way to work within the restriction. And that means code analysis.

Comment: _G["variable"] should work for globals.  Variables inside tables is not an issue, LSL has no such things.  That still leaves locals.  Functions defined inside functions can access the upper level locals, so that might make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution only will work when your Lua variables are all global. Unless this is something LSL also does, you will get trouble translating LSL programs that use variables called the same way in different places.

Lua is only able of modifying one lvalue per statement - tables being passed to functions are the only exception to this rule. You could use a local table to store all locals, and that would help you out with the pre-...-crements; they can be evaluated before the expression they are contained in is evauated. But the post-...-crements have to be evaluated later on, which is simply not possible in lua - at least not without some ugly code involving anonymous functions.

So you have one options: you must accept that some LSL statements will get translated to several Lua statements.

Say you have a LSL statement with increments like this:

```
f(integer x) {
  integer y = x + x++;
  return (y + ++y)
}
```

You can translate this to a Lua statement like this:

```
function f(x) {
  local post_incremented_x = x + 1 -- extra statement 1 for post increment
  local y = x + post_incremented_x
  x = post_incremented_x -- extra statement 2 for post increment

  local pre_incremented_y = y + 1
  return y + pre_incremented_y
  y = pre_incremented_y -- this line will never be executed
}
```

So you basically will have to add two statements per ..-crement used in your statements. For complex structures, that will mean calculating the order in which the expressions are evaluated.

For what is worth, I like with having post decrements and predecrements as individual statements in languages. But I consider it a flaw of the language when they can also be used as expressions. The syntactic sugar quickly becomes semantic diabetes.

Comment: Um, are you referring to my proposed solution using _G?  That was only half the solution, to be used for globals.  Did you see my proposed solution at the end of my question for locals?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it. It's cleaner than mine. Apologies. Ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

In most of your assessment of configurability to the code. You are trying to hard pass data types from one into another. And call it a 'translator'. And in all of this you miss regex and other pattern match capacities. Which are far more present in LUA than LSL. And since the LSL code is being passed into LUA. Try using them, along with other functions. Which would define the work more as a translator, than a hard pass.

Yes I know this was asked a while ago. Though, for other viewers of this topic. Never forget the environments you are working in. EVER. Use what they give you to the best ability you can.